# What happens when entering the US on an international flight?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, luggage

When entering the US on an international flight, and then on to a connecting domestic flight, what is the exact order of the process that will take place? In other words, what happens first, second, third, etc.?

Comment: While the broad outlines are always the same, a couple of questions that will let us give you an answer specific to your situation (i.e. whether you'll need to change terminals). Which airport and airline? Are the international and domestic flights purchased as a single ticket in one transaction, or are they separate tickets?

Comment: I'm sure we already have a question on this. Anyone?

Comment: @ZachLipton I think all of those could be included conditionally in an answer without knowing Donna's specific case, e.g., "You do X, you do Y, then you change terminals if you need to (you can find out by doing ABC), then you do Z." That would make the answer more generically useful.

Comment: @NateEldredge No, that isn't a duplicate. That question asks more about how the particularities of the immigration check however, this question asks more about the particularities of transferring on to a domestic flight.

Comment: Aside: "Entering the US" doesn't always occur where you think it will. [Preclearance Locations](https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance) may cause you to go through the process in a place like Toronto, Canada, or Shannon, Ireland. That's something worth  knowing when you schedule flights to ensure sufficient time where it is needed.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a very general outline.

First, on the plane, you will be asked to fill in a short form for customs. This contains information about who you're travelling with, where you're travelling from, and what you're bringing into the country. It's therefore a good idea to have a pen in your carry on luggage.

After getting off the plane, you come to the immigration check. This is where your visa or ESTA will be checked, and immigration officers will determine if you are allowed in the USA. There may be machines where you are supposed to enter some information before speaking to immigration, depending on the airport.

After clearing immigration, you will pick up your bags and take them through customs. Here you will typically be asked by a customs agent to verify your answers on the customs declaration form you filled in on the plane. The agent will determine if you need to pay any duties or if anything in your luggage needs to be quarantined or destroyed. They may decide to search your bags.

These things will always happen. What happens next depends on the airport and your specific itinerary.

The easiest scenario is that you immediately hand over your bag to a staff member from your airline and proceed to your gate. There may or may not be a security checkpoint before you can go to your connecting flight.

Otherwise, you will need to recheck your luggage and go through a security checkpoint before proceeding to your gate, same as you did to get on the flight to the US.

Comment: Johanna, (+1) great answer, one thing missing is what happens when you need to change terminals (or even airports.)

Comment: Aren’t there still I94 forms to fill, especially if arriving at an airport without kiosks?

Comment: If you come in contact with your checked bags, you will always need to go through security.

Comment: @jcaron depends on the airport. I flew into Houston from Paris a few months ago and there were no forms to fill at all (for either US or non-US people) because of the kiosks. There was also no taking laptops out of bags at re-security, which was excellent. But certainly not the case everywhere.

Comment: @jcaron [Foreign visitors to the U.S. arriving via air or sea no longer need to complete paper Customs and Border Protection Form I-94](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/i-94)

Comment: "There may or may not be a security checkpoint before you can go to your connecting flight." There will _always_ be a security checkpoint before you can continue to your connecting flight if your next flight is on a normal commercial scheduled air carrier (as opposed to, say, a private jet, which doesn't require security checks.)

Comment: @reirab Correct. The reason is that you’ve had access to your checked bags, from which you might have taken an item prohibited in the cabin (e. g. a large knife). Therefore, you will **always** go through security again.

Comment: @Reirab Tiny little commuter planes (under ten seats I think) don't require a security check despite being in every respect a commercial carrier. They are semi common around Hawaii and Alaska. But I'll accept this is a fairly pedantic exception.

Comment: Lately in Miami there is no longer a customs check.

Comment: @Calchas Yeah, those, charters, and private aircraft operate under different rules.

Comment: @Calchas Any exception will surely depend on the airport, rather than the kind of plane. You might only be on a tiny plane but if they let you into the terminal with prohibited items, you could give them to anybody to take on any flight.